# keeping count of the number of times an infinite loop executes

Tags: php

I am wondering if there is a way of keeping a count of the number of times an infinite loop executes

```
while(true){
echo rand(13,20);
sleep(5);
}
```

so that if it executes n times,i can break and exit the program.

Comment: so you want to run the loop n times not infinite times.??

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather use a for loop

Comment: @AnthonySottile We could also write `loop: if ($i++ < 1000) goto loop;`^^

Comment: @Ibrahim.I Nope,i don't want a for loop.

Comment: @Logan I don't see any reason against a for loop? Explain please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just have a counter

```
$count = 0;
while (true) {
  //break after it has executed 1000 times
  if ($count == 1000) break;

  $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By definition then this is not an infinite loop, just use a for loop instead

```
for($x = 0; $x<$max; $x++){
    // do cool stuff here. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some counter variable:

**Decrements Example**

```
$i = 10;
while($i --) {
    // ...
}
```

**Increment Example**

```
$i = 0;
$max = 10;

while($i ++ < $max) {
}
```

**Conditional Increment**

```
$i = 0;
$max = 10;
while($i < $max) {
    // Do some work
    if (/** Work Is done */) {
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This will increment `$i` by one in every loop until `$max` and then stop.

But generally, you should consider using a `for` loop, designed for this type of loop:

```
$max = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Baba Feel free to edit, the answer should be good; that's the most important ;-)

Comment: @Baba Then also update the description of the loop (decrementing instead of incrementing etc.) Btw. I think we should include both examples: with -- and ++...

Comment: Ok let me play with your answer .. while i do that play here http://jakearchibald.github.io/request-quest/ and let me know your score

Comment: @Baba Now It's perfect :-) P.s.: You scored 26 out of 39

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$n = 100;
while ($i < $n)
{
    do_work();
    $i++;
}
```